# Merge two of one dimensional array into two dimensional array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have `n` (but for now, let say just two) of one dimensional arrays like this image of my console :

[image]

And I want to merge these two arrays by the corresponding key and put it into two dimensional array :

The result is something like :

```
[["1 279 226,08" , "127"],[null , null],["-188 033,77", "154"],..... so on ......]
```

And the list of one dimensional array is dynamic, it could be more than 2 arrays.

So example if I have 3 arrays, then my two dimensional array would look like :

```
[ ["1 279 226,08" , "127" , "blabla"], [null , null , "blabla"], ["-188 033,77", "154", "blabla"], ..... so on ......]
```

Any ideas of implementing it would be appreciate.

Comment: please add the raw data in text form as input and the corresponding wanted output and what you have tried.

Comment: Does the one dimensional arrays have fixed length? Are they of the same size?

Comment: @RobertoRusso : The length is dynamic but all the arrays have the same size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all of your arrays have the same size, you can loop just on the lenght of the first array, i.e. `a`.

Then we pass to `appendArrays` the single value of `a` , `b`, ..., and we return the an array to push into `merged`

```js
var a = ["123", null, "ciao"]
var b = ["321", 1, "pippo"]
var c = ["111", 5, "co"]

var merged = []

for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  merged.push(appendArrays(a[i], b[i], c[i]));
}
console.log(merged);

function appendArrays() {
  var temp = []
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    temp.push(arguments[i]);
  }
  return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could transpose the array with a nested loop and switch the indices for assigning the values.

```js
var array = [["1 279 226,08", null, "-188 033,77"], ["127", null, "154"], ["blabla", "blabla", "blabla"]],
    result = array.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        a.forEach(function (b, j) {
            r[j] = r[j] || [];
            r[j][i] = b;
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

```js
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var arr2 = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
var arr3 = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 5];
var arr4 = [12, 34, 55, 77, 22, 426];

var arrCollection = [arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4];

// if array sizes are variable.
// if not max = arrCollection[0].length will do
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, arrCollection.map(function(a) {
  return a.length;
}));

var arrFinal = [];

for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
  var arr = [];
  arrCollection.forEach(function(a) {
    arr.push(a[i]);
  });
  arrFinal.push(arr);
}

console.log(arrFinal);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create this with two `forEach()` loops.

```js
var arr1 = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]];
var arr2 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10, 12, 14]];

let merge = function(arr) {
  var result = [];
  arr.forEach(function(e, i) {
    e.forEach(function(a, j) {
      if (!result[j]) result[j] = [a];
      else result[j].push(a)
    })
  });

  return result;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(merge(arr1)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(merge(arr2)))
```