# push more than one elements at same index in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, zingchart

how to push more than one element at one index of a array in javascript?

like i have

```
arr1["2018-05-20","2018-05-21"];
arr2[5,4];
```

i want resulted 4th array to be like:

```
arr4[["2018-05-20",5],["2018-05-21",4]];
```

tried pushing like this:

```
arr1.push("2018-05-20","2018-05-21");
arr1.push(5,4);
```

and then finally as:

```
arr4.push(arr1);
```

But the result is not as expected. Please someone help.

Actually i want to use this in zingChart as :

**Options Data**
Create an options object, and add a values array of arrays.

**Calendar Values**
In each array, provide the calendar dates with corresponding number values in the following format.

```
 options: {
  values: [
    ['YYYY-MM-DD', val1],
    ['YYYY-MM-DD', val2],
    ...,
    ['YYYY-MM-DD', valN]
  ]
}
```

Comment: There can be only one element at a specified index of an `array`, in all the languages i know. But this element can be an object (even another array) that can contain other things inside it

Comment: You cannot do this: **_push more than one element at one index of a array_**

Comment: I think this is a case of [the XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: You have 2 expected results now with different formats. You might want to choose one. :)

Comment: @Eddie it looks like your answer is what i wanted, but zingChart is not working when i passed the result as values.

Comment: @DeepakVerma I saw that you provided a sample output for zingChart but your initial or given arrays does not match the output. Where `YYYY-MM-DD` and `valX` from?

Comment: @Eddie i showed here just an example, in my code i am using the values in correct format like     ```2018-05-23, 5```

Comment: But you only need 2 values for that, the `date` and the `value`, your code you have 3 arrays.

Comment: @NinaScholz that 3rd value is an extra information that i want to provide please if you can see this docs: [link](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/chart-types/calendar-charts/)

Comment: Maybe it is not working because you are only passing the year and not the whole date.

Comment: @Eddie edited with exactly what i'm try to do

Comment: @DeepakVerma That is the same with my answer, just remove the 3rd array

Comment: it looks now like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46767385/merge-two-of-one-dimensional-array-into-two-dimensional-array-javascript

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming the you want a multidimensional array, you can put all the input variables into an array. Use `reduce` and `forEach` to group the array based on index.

```js
let arr1 = ["2018-05-20","2018-05-21"];
let arr2 = [5,4];

let arr4 = [arr1, arr2].reduce((c, v) => {
  v.forEach((o, i) => {
    c[i] = c[i] || [];
    c[i].push(o);
  });
  return c;
}, []);

console.log(arr4);
```

Comment: That is not the OP's question.

Comment: @NinaScholz - the answer is simple - you cannot **_to push more than one element at one index of a array_**

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not correct at all, since you cannot push more than one element at the same index of an array. Your result is a multidimensional array:

```
[["2018-05-20",5],["2018-05-21",4]]
```

- You have to create a multidimensional array collecting all your data (arrAll)
- Then you create another multidimensional array (arrNew) re-arranging previous data

Try the following:

```js
// Your Arrays
  var arr1 = ["2018-05-20","2018-05-21"];
  var arr2 = [5, 4];
  //var arr3 = [100, 20];
  var arrAll = [arr1, arr2]; 
  //var arrAll = [arr1, arr2, arr3]; 
  
  // New Array definition
  var arrNew = new Array;
  for (var j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
    var arrTemp = new Array
    for (var i = 0; i < arrAll.length; i++) {
      arrTemp[i] = arrAll[i][j];
      if (i === arrAll.length - 1) {
        arrNew.push(arrTemp)
      }
    }
  }
  
  //New Array
  Logger.log(arrNew)
```